# WPF Custom user control binding always return false in listview

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, user-controls, dependency-properties

I've recently started WPF so I'm not understanding everything.
I have a listview in my Xaml file which lists objects of a certain class.

I have created a custom user control ( toggle button ) to switch a bool attribute of the object.
Before, I was using checkboxes and everything was working fine.

Now the binding always returns False.

I can't figure out how to get this working

My class :

```
    public class Macro : INotifyPropertyChanged
{
    public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;

    public const int EDITPIECE = 1, WALLREDITPIECE = 2, DORMIR = 3, NO_ACTION = 0;

    public static double speed = 0;

    private bool _status;
    public bool status {
        get {
            return _status;
        }
        set {
            if (value != this._status)
            {
                this._status = value;
                NotifyPropertyChanged();
            }
        }
    }
    private string _key;
    public string key {
        get
        {
            return _key;
        }
        set
        {
            if (value != this._key)
            {
                this._key = value;
                NotifyPropertyChanged();
            }
        }
    }

    public string _macroname { get; set; }
    public int _action { get; set; }

    ...
    }
```

my ListView :

```
        <ListView Margin="10" Name="lvDataBinding" Width="auto"  Background="Transparent" Foreground="white" BorderThickness="0">
        
        <ListView.ItemTemplate>
            <DataTemplate>
                <WrapPanel>
                    <TextBlock Text="{Binding _macroname}" FontWeight="Bold" />
                    <TextBlock Text="  " />
                    <!-- Checkbox works fine --> <CheckBox IsChecked="{Binding status , Mode=TwoWay, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}" Checked="CheckBoxChanged" Unchecked="CheckBoxChanged"/>
                    <!-- Custom Toggle not working --> <theme:OnOff Height="24" Width="40" Toggle="{Binding status, Mode=TwoWay, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}"/>
                    <TextBlock Text=" key : " />
                    <Button x:Name="keybutton" Content="{Binding key, Mode=TwoWay, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}" Click="keybutton_Click"/>
                </WrapPanel>
            </DataTemplate>
        </ListView.ItemTemplate>
    </ListView>
```

custom user control :

```
public static readonly DependencyProperty ToggleProperty = DependencyProperty.Register("Toggle", typeof(bool), typeof(OnOff), new PropertyMetadata(false));

    public bool Toggle
    {
        get { return (bool)base.GetValue(OnOff.ToggleProperty); }
        set { base.SetValue(OnOff.ToggleProperty, value); }
    }
```

How my list if filled :

```
public partial class Page1 : Page
{
    private List<Macro> listMacroConfig = new List<Macro>();
    public Page1()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        listMacroConfig = ((App)Application.Current)._macros;
        lvDataBinding.ItemsSource = listMacroConfig;
    }
```

Comment: Did you explicitly set the UserControl's DataContext, e.g. in its XAML or code behind? That would be the problem. How do you notice the Binding isn't working? There is no PropertyChangedCallback, and the visualization of the property might not work (you haven't shown us that part).

Comment: As a note, `GetValue(ToggleProperty)` would be equivalent to `base.GetValue(OnOff.ToggleProperty)`.

Comment: Does your OnOff class inherit from the WPF `ToggleButton` class?
If it doesn't, you would need to implement the code that lets mouse and keyboard input change the value of `ToggleProperty` on your own. Your dependency property will bind to the view model property, but none of them will change on user interaction just because they exist. You would need to wire the functionality in your control template...

Comment: Also even if `OnOff` would inherit from `ToggleButton`, clicking on its UI surface would still not be translated to an invocation of the `Toggle` setter. Clicks would still only toggle the `IsChecked` property.

Answer (score 0):

I changed my onOff control to this :

```
public partial class OnOff : UserControl 
{
    static Thickness LeftSide = new Thickness(-16, 0, 0, 0);
    static Thickness RightSide = new Thickness(16, 0,0 , 0);
    
    static SolidColorBrush gray = new SolidColorBrush(Color.FromRgb(139,139,144));
    static SolidColorBrush red = new SolidColorBrush(Color.FromRgb(179, 34, 54));
    static SolidColorBrush transparent = new SolidColorBrush(Color.FromArgb(0,0, 0, 0));



    public static readonly DependencyProperty ToggleProperty = DependencyProperty.Register(nameof(Toggle), typeof(bool), typeof(OnOff), new PropertyMetadata(false, TooglePropertyChangedCallback));


    public bool Toggle
    {
        get { return (bool)base.GetValue(OnOff.ToggleProperty); }
        set { base.SetValue(OnOff.ToggleProperty, value); }
    }

    public OnOff()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }


    private void dot_MouseLeftButtonDown(object sender, MouseButtonEventArgs e)
    {
        Toggle = !Toggle;

    }



    //  This is the callback that will update the background
    private static void TooglePropertyChangedCallback(DependencyObject dependencyObject, DependencyPropertyChangedEventArgs dependencyPropertyChangedEventArgs)
    {
        var target = (OnOff)dependencyObject;

        target.back.Fill = (target.Toggle ? red : transparent);
        target.dot.Margin = (target.Toggle ? RightSide : LeftSide);
        target.dot.Fill = (target.Toggle ? red : gray);

    }



}
```

it works perfectly now, is there something I could improve ?